# Vibration api don't work on android wevview

Tags: vibration

I trying to run the vibration on android 4.4.2 webview app and it does not work.
I use this demo : [Vibration API](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html5-vibration-api--mobile-22585)
. If I run the code on mobile (on chrome browser) its work very good but if i run the code from android webview it does not work.
I add permissions :
    android.permission.INTERNET
    android.permission.VIBRATE
in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: I test it on a android webview with android.permission.VIBRATE and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can [bind Java code to be called from JavaScript](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript) in a WebView, so you could write a plain Java method that operates the vibration, and call that method from the JavaScript in your WebView.

(Disclaimer: Just found it, haven't tried it.)